# Email validation expression \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* allows empty spaces

Tags: regex, email

Email validation expression `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` allows empty spaces, but otherwise works perfectly.

It does not fail the following email address:

```
john doe@hp.edu
```

How can I restrict this to not allow whitespaces?

Comment: Don't try to validate email addresses with regex.  The standard is just too complex.  [Here](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) is an example of how much regex is needed (and it doesn't even fulfill the *whole* standard). In what context are you doing this? I recommend using a module of some kind, as there are plenty of those that do it right.

Comment: I am using it while saving person record .if user enters invalid email address it gives validation error .and while validating that control I am using this regex.

Comment: That wasn't much of an answer. I understand that you are trying to validate email addresses. I'm just saying that regex is not a very good tool for the job. There are modules for most programming languages that do it for you, I recommend using one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs have functionality to match on the entire string, where-as with others it would always search anywhere in the string.

If it's the latter case, it won't fail because a substring, specifically `doe@hp.edu`, matches the pattern.

To fix this, you could either check if the API you're using has a function to match on the entire string, or you could add `^` to the start and `$` to the end of your pattern, indicating the start and end of string / line respectively.

```
^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$
```

Comment: Thanks Dukeling...trying this solved the whitespaces problem but there comes another ,it fails the single letter domain email addresses like doe@m.tk

Comment: @user3467905 - https://regex101.com/ tests out fine for single letter domain and this reg expression as per Bernhard Baker's answer.   i.e. 1 Match