# I am using Regex for email validation EMAIL_PATTERN:/^(\w+([.]\w+)*@\w+([.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*)$/,

Tags: regex, email-validation

I'm Following the below Example:

[Email validation expression \w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* allows empty spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683358/email-validation-expression-w-w-w-w-w-w-allows)

I'm using EMAIL_PATTERN:

```
 `/^(\w+([.]\w+)*@\w+([.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*)$/`
```

with minor changes.
    It is allowing me to enter the email as i want but i dont want "_" at the
    starting of the email address. Example: `_abc@gmail.com`
    How to solve this?
    What regex google is using in gmail?

Comment: `\w` is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so switch it out with a character class instead and remove the underscore. Keep in mind that your regex allows for an email that starts with an at sign (since the entire group before the at sign is `*`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: Read this http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html about validating email via regex. It is very comprehensive. BTW an email could start with `_`.

Comment: What language are you writing this in? You're much better off using an email validation library. For example, [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid) in Perl.

Comment: I am using angular js. I have updated it like below as mentioned by h200000:
/^(\[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.]\[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@\w+([.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*)$/
is it correct?? I trid this but its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: The [validator regex in Parsley.js](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/src/parsley/validator_registry.js) is one of the better I've seen in Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo i changed \w with below:
 /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@\w+([.]\w+)*\.\w+([.]\w+)*)$/ is it correct or not??

Comment: stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo Thanks !! it is working as per my requirements now.

Answer (score -1):

Use This

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)@\w+([.]\w+)\.\w+([.]\w+)*)$/,
```